# Unable to set SMPP optional parameter in go code

Tags: go, smpp

Iam studying SMPP protocol and tried to implement a simple transmitter with a golang code and **selenium smpp simulator**. I found a package "**CodeMonkeyKevin/smpp34**" from github. 
But Iam unable to set the "user_message_reference" optional parameter.

I slightly modified the "SubmitSm" function inside the "transmitter.go" file by adding these lines (just before the write operation):

```
err = p.SetTLVField(tag, length, []byte(value))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Set TLV failed")
        return 0, err
    }
```

But this is not working.

I supplied values **tag=0516**(int equivalent of 0x0204 user_message_reference) **length=02** and **value="91"**.

In the response i could see "**tag=516,len=2,value=0x3931**" in the SMSC simulator , the value field doesn't seem appropriate to me; also the "**message_id**" in the response still continues its sequence by adding 1 with the last message_id

can some one help me in setting the "user_message_reference" optional parameter to the "**submit_sm**" request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean you are "unable to set the user_message_reference optional parameter"? Please show an example of what you tried, what you expect to happen, and what you actually saw.

Comment: I supplied values tag=0516(int equivalent of 0x0204 user_message_reference) length=02 and value="91" in the setTVLField function. 
I could see "tag=516,len=2,value=0x3931" appear in the SMSC simulator , but the value doesn't seem appropriate to me; and the message_id in the response still continues its sequence by adding 1 with the last message_id.

Comment: @JimB did that help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have edit the function in the transmitter.go

just set your tlv fields after your submit_sm

example

```
pdu, err        := trx.Smpp.SubmitSm("+254720000000", 
pdu.GetField("source_addr").String(), msg, &smpp.Params{})

pdu.SetTLVField(0x0501, 1, []byte{2}) #eg a ussd_service_op
```

This is the proper way to add your tlv values if you are using kevin's package
See https://github.com/CodeMonkeyKevin/smpp34/issues/9
[Additional parameters](https://github.com/CodeMonkeyKevin/smpp34/issues/9)